# Form is not submitting via javascript on a button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css, forms

My website has been created with a CSS/HTML frame work that has been integrated into an ASP.NET website.

Inside of a ContentPlaceHolder, I have a simple login form. The catch is that I am using the onclick event of an image to submit the form. It normally works pretty straight forward, but this time I am having an issue.

```
<div id="login">
    <form action="index.aspx" method="post" id="nothingForm" name="nothingForm">
    </form>
    <form action="https://google.com.au" method="post" id="loginform" name="loginform">
        <input type="text" name="uname" value="username" onfocus="if(!this._haschanged){this.value=''};this._haschanged=true;"/>
        <input type="password" name="pword" value="password" onfocus="if(!this._haschanged){this.value=''};this._haschanged=true;"/>
    </form>
    <br /><img src="images/login.gif" alt="" onclick="document['loginform'].submit()" />    </div>
```

I have to stick another form before the real form to make onclick="document['loginform'].submit()" actually work. This should not be the case, of course, but I was unable to find any solutions to it on the web.

Has anyone else come across this before?

Comment: Check and see if your content place holder is inside a form. That can cause form submit issues...

Comment: Why not use Server side controls anyway? You're using ASP.NET, there's a built in login widget...

Comment: You're code seems to work, even without the "nothingForm". Can you reproduce the problem on a public site or on JSBin.com? Are you having this problem with a particular browser?

Comment: I agree, this should work w/o the blank form.  Post your full code, the problem (if one exists) is probably elsewhere.

Comment: @EJC The ContentPlaceHolder is inside of the required ASP.NET form.

Comment: @vol7ron - There should be affecting it in the c# code and you can see all the css/html etc at the two above links.

Comment: As [Guffa](http://stackoverflow.com/users/69083/guffa) stated below a form cannot have an internal form.  You need to close the first one before you open the second.  Your "dummy" form is merely closing the first form so your second can open and register correctly.

Comment: @brianpeiris I had posted the links to a couple of pages, but I have removed them since my problem has been found. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the page already has a form around all the code. Forms can not be nested, so your first form tag will be ignored, and it's end tag will end the outer form.

You have to place your form outside the already existing form.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks Guffa! Never would have thought to check for nested forms...

Answer (score 2):

Did you try out `document.getElementById("loginform").submit()`? I would think this is better, since I have never seen anyone access elements on the document itself like that before. May be some kind of strange side effect.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did try that with no luck.

Comment: ...or document.forms["form-id"].submit()